# How come this RegExp doesn't work when passed in as a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Chrome 9.0.597.83 beta on Ubuntu 10.10:

[image]

As you can see, the pattern doesn't work when passed in as a string, but works fine when passed in as a RegExp object. Why is this? I need to be able to pass it in as a string so that I can manipulate it before performing the match.

---

<sub>**Note:** I just posted a question very similar to this... and thought I was doing something wrong and deleted the question. Then when I tried something slightly different, I got the problem again.</sub>

Comment: Now I'm getting the problem too, but only with `"e c"`.

Comment: @Bolt: Yeah, me too now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the backslash `\`.  This is escaping the `W` character. In a string, `\W` evaluates to `W`. You need to escape the *backslash*:

```
"e c".match(new RegExp('(?:^|\\W)c(?:\\W|$)'))
```

Comment: *[Facepalm]* Why didn't I think of that? Good job.

Comment: @George It took doing `console.log(new RegExp('(?:^|\W)c(?:\W|$)'))` to make me figure it out!